# Doubt about exercise on family of circles

Tags: metric-geometry

Consider the following family of cirles
$$
x^2+y^2-2x+4y-2+k(x^2+y^2-6y+8)=0
$$
We are asked about the value of $k$ so that the circle will have the center on the straight line given by the equation
$$
y=-8x.
$$
The result given by the book is $k=-2$.

Here the steps I've followed and an and an in-depth study I wanted to do that led me to a situation where I may not have understood the theory properly.

**Solution 1).** From the equation of the family of circles I'have found the espression of the coordinate of the center as function of $k$ with $(k \neq -1)$
$$
C:\left(\frac{1}{1+k},\frac{3k-2}{1+k}\right)
$$
To find the value of $k$ as requested by the exercise the follwing equation shall hold
$$
\frac{3k-2}{1+k} = -8\frac{1}{1+k}
$$
Solving the equation gives the expected result i.e. $k=-2$.
So far so good.

Now the less understood part.

**Solution 2).** Using the equation of the family of circles and by putting $k=-1$ we can obtain a degenerate circle the belong to the family and that can be used to write the equation of the family of circles too.
The equation of the degenerate circle is
$$
C_1: -x+5y-5=0
$$
which is a straight line i.e. a circle with infinite radius.
As far as I know, nothing should prevent me to write the equation above as
$$
C_2: x-5y+5=
0.$$
Now if I write the family of cicles using one of the original circle (specifically $x^2+y^2-6y+8$) and the degenerate one, and apply the steps followed in *solution 1*, except for the $(k \neq -1)$ condition, I will obtain
$$
\begin{split}
x^2+y^2-6y+8 + k(-x+5y-5) &= 0 \implies  k= -2\\
x^2+y^2-6y+8 + k(x-5y+5) &= 0 \implies  k=+2 !!!
\end{split}
$$
I cannot understand how this is possible. Is it due to the $k \neq-1$ condition no longer being applied? Where is the error?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, that sounds really clear. Thanks a lot

Comment: Since the question has been migrated, I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your final displayed equation
$$
x^2 + y^2 - 6y + 8 + k(x - 5y + 5) = 0
$$
it is a "mistake" to reuse the parameter $k$.  Let's instead use the parameter $\ell$. So the family becomes
$$
D_\ell : x^2 + y^2 - 6y + 8 + \ell(x - 5y + 5) = 0
$$
We also have (in your second to last displayed equation) the family
$$
E_k : x^2 + y^2 - 6y + 8 + k(-x+5y-5) = 0
$$
"Clearly" these are the "same" families of circles but with $E_k = D_{-\ell}$. This explains the sign change.

Comment: went trough the math once again and found K=-2 and l=2 both passing the check with the straight line. So how do we chose the final result? thanks

Comment: They are the “same” answer, represented in different ways.  This is sort of similar to (but more subtle than) the “fact” that 2/4 is the “same” as 1/2.

Comment: Does it relate to the fact that the degenerate circle has been used to write the family?

Comment: It relates to the fact that, by changing the sign, you changed the parametrisation of the family.  Here is a simpler example: consider the curve $\alpha(t) = (t, t^2)$ in the plane (with $t$ ranging over the reals).  Is this the same as, or different from, $\beta(t) = (-t, t^2)$?